# Contador aumentando con variables de sesión (PHP-$_SESSION)

Tags: php

Estoy sacando el adivinar un número secreto mediante $_SESSION, esa parte la he sacado, pero ahora necesito que me cuente los intentos que llevo, he estado probando con la estructura de $_SESSION['variable'] e ir sumando, pero siempre se me queda en 1, no aumenta por cada intento que pruebo.

Os dejo el código PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adivina el valor oculto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Advinando el número..</h1>
<?php
function genValor() {
return $var = rand(0, 10);
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['valor_aleat'])) $_SESSION['valor_aleat'] = genValor();
if (isset($_REQUEST['numero']))
{
    $_SESSION['intentos'] = 0;
    $Num_Recibido = $_REQUEST['numero'];
    $Num_Aleatorio = $_SESSION['valor_aleat'];
    echo "Número secreto";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $Num_Aleatorio;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Número introducido por ti";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $Num_Recibido;
    echo "<br>";

    if ($Num_Aleatorio == $Num_Recibido) {
    echo "<H1>Numero acertado</H1>";
    echo '<a href="./Adivino.html"> Iniciar nueva partida </a>';
    unset ($_SESSION['valor_aleat']);
     ++$_SESSION['intentos'];    
    } 

    else {
    if ($Num_Recibido < $Num_Aleatorio) {
    echo "Numero incorrecto, el valor es mayor";
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<a href="./Adivino.html"> Volver a la 1º Pagina </a>';
        ++$_SESSION['intentos'];
    } else {
    echo "Número incorrecto, el valor es menor";
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<a href="./Adivino.html"> Volver a la 1º Pagina </a>';
        ++$_SESSION['intentos'];
    }

    }
}
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Numero de intento:";
    echo $_SESSION['intentos'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahí tenéis todo, yo pido un número secreto para que me lo saque pero no me deja hacer bien la operación de contar todos los intentos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la forma correcta de incrementar `intentos` seria algo así.

```
$_SESSION['intentos'] = $_SESSION['intentos']++
```

Prueba y me comentas. 
Código sin probar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero tampoco me va, el contador siempre se queda a cero, entiendo que el ++ no debe de ir ahí.